# auto update table in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem. I was trying to make a table on a website. Everytime the user add a record it would display on the website. The user can add many more record on the table. My question is how do i make the table display the record automatically without saving the data into a database and retreiving it to dispaly on the the website table?

Answer (score 1):

You can take benefit of `gridview`, `datatable` and `viewstate`.

Initially you can create a `datatable` and bind it in `gridview`
Also keep the `datatable` in the `viewstate`
Next time when user add some data add a new row in `data-table`
Update the `viewstate` data.
And again Bind the `gridview`.

### Edit 1

Adding data to datatable

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.column.Add("Name",typeof(string));
dt.column.Add("Age",typeof(int));

DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"]="Mohammad"; // or dr[0]="Mohammad";
dr["Age"]=24; // or dr[1]=24;
dt.add.rows(dr);

dr=dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"]="Shahnawaz"; // or dr[0]="Shahnawaz";
dr["Age"]=24; // or dr[1]=24;
dt.add.rows(dr);

GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

store your datatable in view state

```
ViewState["dataTable"] = dt;
```

Now suppose you have text boxes t1 and t2

```
Datatable dt=ViewState["dataTable"] as DataTable;
dr=dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"]=t1.text; // or dr[0]="Shahnawaz";
dr["Age"]=t2.text; // or dr[1]=24;
dt.add.rows(dr);
```

Bind it to gridview again

```
GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and keep the datatable in the view state

```
ViewState["dataTable"] = dt;
```